# Firebase data retrieval returns an empty screen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase to a listview...However this code returns a blank screen .My database has got 3 children with for data fields each.

All i see is an empty screen.

I have no idea on how to solve this anyone please:The code is here

```
public class Business extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView business;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> arr;
    public ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        arr = new ArrayList<>();

        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                map2list((Map) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //formats the datasnapshot entries to strings
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //makes the ListView realtime
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                System.out.println(databaseError.toException());
                // ...
            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener((com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener) listener);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.business);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void map2list(Map<String,Long> map){

        arr.clear();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            Long key = Long.parseLong(entry.getKey());
            String d = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(key);
            Long value = entry.getValue();
            arr.add(d + ": " + value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't know how to solve this? You've essentially asked others to debug this on your behalf. It seems likely that you could find the answer by isolating the parts and seeing which one isn't producing the desired outcome: a) does it work if you take Firebase out of the picture? b) does it work if you take the UI out of the picture? c) can you directly query that URL and get results? Can you log results at each step to verify where the code stops executing? Also consider turning on debug logging using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`

Answer (score 0):

If the whole page is blank when you set the content view, this might have happened if one of your views in your layout has a layout_height attribute of 'match parent'.  This may be one of the reasons why you are not seeing anything. Another reason why you might not bee seeing anything is that listeners run on separate threads. Try rearranging your code like this.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.business);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

mDatabase.addValueEventListener((com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener) listener);
// add the listner after setting the adapter
```